# Using Lagrange multiplier to find maximum value.

Tags: calculus, optimization

The maximum value of the function $f(x, y) = xy$, and subject to condition $x^2+y^2=1$:

So do I apply Lagrange's Multiplier method to find the maximum value?
I tried to find the numbers just by applying few numbers but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

how about this inequality : $ x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$ it would simplify things.

Comment: right so the maximum value of xy has to be 1/2. is that correct?

Comment: @ActuallyanActuary yes, that's correct.

Comment: that makes it really simple. Thanks a lot Amire!

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use Lagrange Multipliers, you could do the following:

$$f(x,y) = xy\\
g(x,y) = x^2+y^2 = 1$$

So

$$\nabla f(x,y) = < f_x,f_y>=<y,x>, \,\mathrm{and}\, \nabla g(x,y) = <g_x,g_y> = <2x,2y>$$

Now for the method of Lagrange Multipliers, we must find all values of $x$, $y$, $\lambda$ such that

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y)\\
x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

So 
$$f_x = \lambda g_x \,\,\mathrm{and}\,\, f_y=\lambda g_y$$

Thus we must solve
$$
y=2\lambda x\\
x=2\lambda y \\
x^2+y^2=1
$$

If we rearrange the second equation for $y$, we get

$$ y = \frac{x}{2\lambda} $$

So

$$ 2 \lambda x = \frac{x}{2\lambda} \\
4\lambda^2x=x\\
4\lambda^2x-x=0\\
x(4\lambda^2-1)=0\\
$$

So $x=0$, $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$

If 
$x=0$,

$y=2\lambda (0) = 0$

BUT if $x=y=0$, then the condition $x^2+y^2=1$ does not hold. So $x$,$y\neq 0$

If $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$, $y=x$

So 
$$x^2+x^2 = 1\\
2x^2=1\\
x^2=\frac{1}{2}\\
x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
$$

Now $y=x$, so $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ when $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ when $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Thus 
$$f(x,y) = xy = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}$$

That was a lot of work just to get the same answer as @Amire...

Comment: yeah but I think it's good to know this way as well! Thanks a lot davie!